# Unable to run dotnet under certain directories?

Tags: linux, .net-core

I am using the command: `dotnet "myfile.dll"`

Initially it was giving me this error: `The user's home directory could not be determined. Set the 'DOTNET_CLI_HOME' environment variable to specify the directory to use.`

Now after messing around with it, I have moved my files to `c:/mydir`, and it is giving this error: `Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80070057`. I found [this](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/969#issuecomment-174042192), but isn't `c:/mydir` a drive root?

Couple of things I noted:

1. I am able to run the .dll fine in a different directory.
2. Both directories contain same files.

The reason I want to run it in `c:/mydir` is because I am using AWS CodeDeploy, and that is where it copies the files (as far as I know; and the other directories are just the old versions where the files get copied from).

These issues are not linked (the first one I get from running a automated shell script after installation, and the second I get from manually trying to launch the .dll).
If someone could help me solve either one of these issues it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are talking about `C:` but have this question tagged as `linux`. Are you using WSL? Or plain Linux or plain Windows?

Comment: @OmairMajid Ah thanks for pointing that out, I didn't know linux didn't have drives labeled like windows. Here is my linux machine image: https://imgur.com/a/YveiGOo I found that the dir is actually `root/c:/mydir`

Comment: I am going to change the dir to `root/mydir` and see if that fixes it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `Environment=DOTNET_CLI_HOME=/temp` to your Service declaration in your `.service` file. Example syntax:

```
[Service]
...
Environment=VARNAME=VARCONTENTS
```

So the actual like would look like this

```
Environment=DOTNET_CLI_HOME=/temp
```